# processing xls file in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, xls

I need to process xls files and create records from them, automatically, in APEX of flow.
I know there is no native salesforce solution for it, what is the best way of doing so?

Comment: xls or xlsx? Recent developments in Apex make it theoretically possible to handle the latter, if the files are small enough.

Answer (score 3):

### Tl;dr: The best way to do this in Salesforce is to not do it in Salesforce

The best way is probably to use a third party service instead of Salesforce (flows, Apex, etc...)

Salesforce isn't a platform for general computing, and the governor limits make it difficult to work with all but the most basic of file formats (and xls/xlsx are complex beasts) even if you find/make some Apex that is able to parse them.

xlsx, for example, is basically a fancy `.zip` file, and Zippex can unzip that, but anything larger than about 34 kB (suggested by [issue #16<sup>1</sup> on the github repo](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex/issues/16)) runs into the CPU limit; and that's just getting at the xml, not even parsing the xml.

Even as little as 500 rows with 4 integer columns, 3 email columns, and 3 general string columns is likely going to exceed that.

Using a dataweave script in Apex may be a better approach than trying to do something with Apex alone, but that specifically cannot handle xlsx. It does, however, appear to support the older xls format (which is a binary format).

Even if you can use Dataweave (or the `Compression.ZipReader` in developer preview at time of writing mentioned by sfdcfox), the CPU and Heap Space governor limits will dictate the size of data you can feasibly work with. Going off-platform (or possibly to Heroku) is going to mean you have a lot fewer restrictions.

<sup>1: There was some research done into making the blob->int conversion faster with pr #20, but it doesn't look like that work ever made it into a release. Even if you found a fork that did use that, it's at most an 18x speedup, meaning you'd be able to unzip up to about a 620 kB file. That's still without processing it into records, though.</sup>

Comment: +1, but note that Apex now has [native ZIP support](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_compression.htm&release=248&type=5). I haven't tested it for performance, but I think Dom.Document + Compression.ZipReader could probably process decently larger files than Zippex could handle.

Comment: @sfdcfox oh no, now I'm somewhat interested. Assuming the unzip part is handled, it looks relatively straightforward to get meaningful data out of a simple xlsx. `./xl/worksheets/sheetX.xml`, `<sheetData>` is 1 level down from the root, with rows/cells/values, and cells reference data from `./xl/sharedStrings.xml` when we see the attribute/value `t="s"` in the cell element.